# Why would you used '--track' options in git branches?

Tags: git

This is my understanding about tracking git branches, please correct me if I am missing something here. To track a remote branch, you would first run `git fetch origin`, which brings a copy image of the remote git repository. Let's say you list the branches you want to create a tacking branch to `mybranch`, you'd simply run `git branch mybranch` and then git will automatically create a remote branch and make it tracking the corresponding (name correlation) remote branch. Very simple! 
The question is, why do most of the git folks talk about the option `--track` if git is capable to identify the branch you just create (based on name correlation) is available in `origin` or remote repository?

Comment: Because there are cases when you want to track other branch or remote, not what Git tries to track by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some other details that are not quite right but the key is here:

> you'd simply run `git branch mybranch` and then git will ... make it tracking the corresponding (name correlation) remote branch

When you use `git branch mybranch` to create a branch, it *doesn't* do that.  It *does* do that, at least by default, if you run `git branch mybranch origin/mybranch`.

If you use `git branch mybranch`, though, Git creates `mybranch` based on the current commit hash, as if you had done:

```
git branch mybranch $(git rev-parse HEAD)
```

and the default behavior when naming a remote-tracking branch is controlled by the configuration setting in `branch.autoSetupMerge`.

The `git checkout` command will also sometimes, but not always, create a new branch using an implied `--track` and remote-tracking branch.  Specifically, given `git checkout name`, there are numerous optional paths, depending on whether *`name`* can be resolved:

- *`name`* is the name of an existing branch: `git checkout` tries to switch to that existing branch.
- *`name`* is the name of an existing tag, or otherwise resolves to a commit through the multi-step procedure described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html): `git checkout` tries to check out that particular commit as a detached HEAD.
- *`name`* is *not* any of the above, but there exists *exactly one* remote-tracking branch which, if stripped of its remote, matches *`name`* (e.g., you enter `git checkout develop` when there is no `develop` but there is an `origin/develop`): in this case, Git will create a new branch `develop` that "tracks" (has as its upstream) `origin/develop`, just as `git branch` would with the appropriate arguments and appropriate `branch.autoSetupMerge` and/or `branch.autoSetupRebase` settings.

If all of the above fail, `git checkout` tries interpreting *`name`* as a path name.  You can force `git checkout` to skip the above steps (and go straight for the path name interpretation) using the `--` option-terminator: `git checkout -- master` means *check out a **file** named `master`* and not a branch.

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

The automatic tracking you mention is a convenience "shorthand", but it doesn't always work.

Sometimes there are multiple remotes with the same branch name; in that case git doesn't know which one to track and won't automatically set up tracking info.

Also, sometimes you want a local branch to track a remote branch that *doesn't* have the same name.

Some developers might, I suppose, never need to explicitly set tracking info; but some do, so you can.

Comment: OK that makes a lot of sense to use --track based on what you said "Sometimes there are multiple remotes with the same branch name". Thank you! I wish I can up vote your answer but I don't have enough reputation!